# how to make div static in css

Tags: html, css

i have a div inside its parent div and code is shown below

```
<div style="width:100%;height:400px;"><!--main_div-->
<div id="left_container" style="width:float:left;width:220px;height:1000px;"></div>
<div id="middler" style="float:left;width:800px;height:800px;background-color:#333;"></div>
</div><!--end_of_main_div-->
```

this code is perfectly HTMLized in browser

But when i resize browser(change the width of the browser window) the div(middler) is weirdly pushed below the main div .. why is it happening

like this page is perfectly spread even when the browser is re-sized
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YcpwaeP11pY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of this:

```
   float:left;
```

What it's telling the browser is: Put these on the same line if there is enough room. If there isn't, drop it a line.

You're giving it set pixel widths, so it will always drop to the next line when changing window size.

Instead of using widths set by pixel, try using percentages instead.

Comment: when i am not using float:left the two divs are placed one above another

Comment: That makes sense. Try changing your widths from 220px and 800px to 20% and 80% respectfully(depending on default margins/padding, you may want to drop it a percentage or two, or also add negative margins to compensate).

Answer (score 1):

Because `float:left` will only **try** and hug the adjacent div if it can. It's is no guarantee that the div will align to the right of the first div. It will only do so if it has enough space within the browser window.

If you want to keep the div entitled 'middler' to the right of your other div, you'll have to either use percentages or used fixed/absolute positioning.

The question alone is none-too specific, in my opinion.

You also have an error in your syntax on line 2:

This:

```
width:float:left;
```

Should really be this:

```
float:left;
```

But this probably won't solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because if the browser width is ess than 1020px, there is no longer enough room to fit both boxes side-by-side, so one of them has to give.

Comment: but why it is perfect when we resize during http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YcpwaeP11pY

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the size in percentages.
Like someone already said, if you set it to pixels the size is static and if the browser doesn't have space to fit both horizontally it will try to fit them vertically.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a static min-width for your main div:

```
<div style="width:100%; min-width: 1020px; height:400px;">
```

Note: when you add a padding, margin or border to #left-container or #middler you should add that number to the min-width from your main div.